# Change background color back if clicked elsewhere

Tags: jquery, css, tabs, background-color

I am using this code to load some content of a div as well as change the color of the tab the user clicked on. I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the background color change back once the user clicks on something else. How would I do that?

```
$(function() {
        $('#tab-1').click(function() {
            var tabcontent = "<?php echo preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", addslashes($tabcontent[0]));?>";
            document.getElementById('top-tabs-content').innerHTML = tabcontent;
            $(this).css("background-color","#F7C703");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#tab-1').click(function() {
        var tabcontent = "<?php echo preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", addslashes($tabcontent[0]));?>";
        document.getElementById('top-tabs-content').innerHTML = tabcontent;
        $('.tabclass').css("background-color","#defaultcolour");
        $(this).css("background-color","#F7C703");
    });
});
```

Add a `class` to the elements, then before applying the colour to `clicked` `element`, reset all the `elements` with the default colour.

Comment: Thank you, this worked and was easy to integrate into my existing code.

Comment: Ah, one snag though. This seemed to kill my `#tab-1:hover` styling. I tried adding `$('.toptabs:hover').css("background-color","#F7C703");` but that didn't seem to work. How can I bring that back?

Comment: ok, this is fine, add a style to your css ie: `.clickedTab {"background-color","#F7C703"}` then, rather than use the `.css()` function to add the desired css, use the `.addClass("clickedTab")` and `.removeClass("clickedTab")` functions to add an remove the style that is linked to the class.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind a click handler to the `document` object and use the `.closest()` method:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ( !$(e.target).closest('#tab-1').length ) {
       $('#tab-1').css("background-color", '');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6g8g7/

Comment: Good answer, thank you. I saw the other one first and it worked, but this method would work as well.