# Add class to element when clicked, Remove when clicked outside of element

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm new to Jquery and want your help. I'm using this code and trying to add class to en element and it ok but i also want that when we click outside. The class should be remove automatically. Please help!

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $("#active").addClass("selected");
  });

<ul>
     <li><a href="#" class="flip" id="active">Restaurants</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what do you mean by click outside

Comment: outside of an element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change background color back if clicked elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072838/change-background-color-back-if-clicked-elsewhere)

Comment: you should mark Vedant Terkar's answer as accepted

Comment: @ZenMaster From where to accept it? I'm new here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you need to remove class when click outside of that element occurs, Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#active").click(function(e){
    var e=window.event||e;
    $("#active").addClass("selected");
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
$(document).click(function(e){
    $("#active").removeClass("selected");
});
});
<ul>
     <li><a href="#" class="flip" id="active">Restaurants</a></li>
</ul>
```

Hope it'll help you !

Comment: blur should do the trick, instead of binding click to document and stopping event propagation on #active manually

Comment: @ZenMaster Yeah! I think that too. But blur can't work if element doesn't support that. `ex: DIV is that element`.

Comment: @user3212226 I'm glad that i could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to click on the document, then you won't get the `blur` event. So it won't work. However you can try out this:

```
$('selector').blur(function () {
  // remove class..
}
```

Learn about the blur event here: http://api.jquery.com/blur/

`blur` is the event, which is opposite for `focus`. Focus event is triggered once the user click on the element or selects it using <kbd>tab</kbd> key. Once the element is in focus, it can be called the state when the user can write input to the fields.

Whereas blur is the condition when the elements looses the focus and the user provides focus to some other element, such as by pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> key or by clicking outside of the element.